# GridSearch 'UndefinedMetricWarning' and bad result

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have created a simple script to apply a grid search on a random forest classifier and while i have worked with it in the past, it seems to be broken now and i cant find why.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1).fit(X, y)


grid_values = {'criterion':['gini','entropy'], 'max_features':['log2', 5, 10, 15, 20, 25], 'max_depth':[None, 5, 10, 15, 20],
               'min_samples_split':[2, 3],'n_jobs':[-1], 'class_weight': [{0 : 1., 1: 30.}, {0 : 1., 1: 50.}, {0 : 1., 1: 100.}]}

for eval_metric in ('precision', 'accuracy'):
  rfc_custom = GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid=grid_values, scoring=eval_metric)
  rfc_custom.fit(X_train, y_train)
  rfc_custom.best_params_
  print('Grid best parameter (max. {0}): {1}'
         .format(eval_metric, rfc_custom.best_params_))
  print('Grid best score ({0}): {1}'
         .format(eval_metric, rfc_custom.best_score_))
```

When i run this, i get the following warning:

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples.
```

Searching online, i added this code and the warning stops:

```
import warnings
import sklearn.exception

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=sklearn.exceptions.UndefinedMetricWarning)
```

After running the algorithm i get a precision of 0.0

Is this normal because of the warning im getting? Am i maybe missing something?

Comment: The below code only hides the warning but dont change the behaviour of the algorithm. The problem is that in the predicted values, there is some class, which in never predicted by the algorithm, so precision is undefined for that.

Comment: Which line did emit the warning?

Comment: It is emited in the 'GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid=grid_values, scoring=eval_metric)' line.  From my understanding each cross validation produces this error since multiple errors for the same metric are produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there were no TP and FP samples on some CV condition, so zero divisive have happened inside the GridSearchCV. It would happen if validation data has no data for a label , or all samples were somehow miss-classified into others.

memo:The definition of precision is (TP) / (TP+FP), where TP is true positive and FP is false positive.

Comment: This does make sense since i used only a few lines (1000 lines) in an uneven dataset, just to check if my algorithm works.

Is there a way to confirm that all cross validation samples are stratified?

Comment: You need to manually separate the data set by [StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold).

Comment: Then, draw a [confusion matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py) and check each predicted label has at least one sample.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a good way to extract such a information from GridSearchCV object...